# NullPointerException in CXF REST invoke method when passing a null parameter

Tags: java, web-services, rest, cxf

I'm consuming a REST web service which exposes a method like

```
    public boolean uploadConfig(String configContent);
```

In my client I annotated this interface in this way:

```
    public boolean uploadConfig(@WebParam(name = "configContent") String configContent);
```

So that 'configContent' param should be a Body parameter.

The problem is that if I pass a null configContent, a NullPointerException is thrown from ClientProxyImpl.invoke() method.

I surely can check in my code for the null-ness of the input param, but I'd like to know how may I manage this check natively with CXF client lib.
Perhaps some annotation missing in the interface?

Thank you very much!

Best

cghersi

Answer (score 1):

The @WebParam annotation is only applicable for JAX-WS.

Assuming you are trying to send the data as in an HTML form post, you should annotate the parameter with the JAX-RS [@FormParam](https://jax-rs-spec.java.net/nonav/2.0/apidocs/javax/ws/rs/FormParam.html).

`public boolean uploadConfig(@FormParam("configContent") String configContent);`

A null value will result in no parameter being sent with the request.